# Can a school admin see my search history?

Tags: administrator

On my own device, on my own network, but using my school's google account (with their domain), can a school admin see my search history? More specifically, I know they can reset the password and log in/perform a vetting for a specific account, but can they search through all their students' search history for a specific query and link it back to a particular google account?

Comment: What device are you referring to?

Comment: Are you asking about your _Google_ search history specifically? Did you log in to your account in the browser too (e.g: Chrome), and do you have sync enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, While they can see your account activity, they can't even see your search history (except for legally required procedures in your country of residence - see below). See [this google page](https://workspace.google.com/terms/education_privacy/#privacy-police-revamp-controls):

> As described fully in the Google Privacy Policy and the Google Cloud Privacy Notice, we do not share your personal information with companies, organizations, or individuals outside of Google except in the following cases:
>
> 1. With your school’s admin: Your admin and resellers who manage your or your organization’s Workspace account will have access to your information. For example, they may be able to:
>
>    ▪ View account information, activity and statistics;
>
>    ▪ Change your account password;
>
>    ▪ Suspend or terminate your account access;
>
>    ▪ Access your account information in order to satisfy applicable law, regulation, legal process, or enforceable governmental request;
>
>    ▪ Restrict your ability to delete or edit your information or your privacy settings.

See also [this related thread](https://support.google.com/a/thread/38079337/can-my-administrator-see-my-search-history?hl=en)

Remember though that they might be able to see anything that you share with others.

However, should you ever use a windows device that is registered to your school, the admin of such device might access any information which is visible to you on such device, **including the search history which comes from your use on a different device**.

**EDIT:**
The above of course is true ONLY if you have set a password your admin does not know. They could of course set a new password at any moment, and with that one enter into your account.

EDIT 2: What is intended by "account activity" can be seen on [this google workspace help page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4580176?hl=en#general&gmail&drive&classroom)

Comment: What exactly does account activity mean?

Comment: @rokkc See here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/4580176?hl=en#general&gmail&drive&classroom